# Read script until delimiter and echo result that is piped for command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a cypher script that consists of multiline cypher queries that are delimited by a specific string e.g. `-delmiter-`.

I want to echo each of these segments into the cypher shell in a container and get the query that was sent into the cypher shell and the output of the shell.

When using dummy code it would be like this

```
#!/bin/bash
while read $multilinesegment
do
   echo $multilinesegment
   docker exec -i neo4j_container /bin/cypher-shell -u user -p password --format=verbose
done <<< import.cypher #-delimitedby'-delimiter-'
```

How can I split the script into these segments and run a loop with it?

edit:
My `import.cypher` looks like this:

```
match (a:Person)-[:Is_maried_to]-(b)
set b.last_name=a.last_name
return a,b;
-delimiter-
match (a:Person)-[:Is_maried_to]-(b)
set b.last_name=a.last_name
return a,b;
-delimiter-
match (a:Person)-[:Is_maried_to]-(b)
set b.last_name=a.last_name
return a,b;
-delimiter-
match (a:Person)-[:Is_maried_to]-(b)
set b.last_name=a.last_name
return a,b;
-delimiter-
```

Comment: @maulinglawns sorry I wasn't finished with my question yet. I hope my edit cleares things up?

Comment: Please also i) show us an example of your input; ii) tell us what shell you are using. You had tagged this as Ubuntu but that can easily mean either dash or bash or something else; and iii) clarify why you are calling your variable "multiline". Is this going to be a string that contains `\n` characters?

Comment: @terdon I specified the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

Can `-delimiter-` be a blank line?

```
match (a:Person)-[:Is_maried_to]-(b)
set b.last_name=a.last_name
return a,b;

match (a:Person)-[:Is_maried_to]-(b)
set b.last_name=a.last_name
return a,b;

...
```

If so

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  RS=""
  command = "docker exec -i neo4j_container /bin/cypher-shell -u user -p password --format=verbose"
} {
  print | command
  close command
}' import.cypher
```

and then you do not need the (slow and) bad at reading lines `while read` loop. Bad in the sense that if the ultimate line lacks a newline, that line is

```
(echo one; echo -n two) | while read l; do echo $l; done
```

whoops! silent data loss!

Comment: Is there a way to use a specific delimiter?

Comment: yes, but it complicates the code as you will likely need to switch to line-by-line parsing and accumulating not delimiter lines, etc that `RS=""` in paragraph mode already gives you

Comment: line by line parsing would be a while read loop, correct?

Comment: no, that would be the bad slow way. `awk` would be much faster and have a lower risk of silent data loss